# Having error when "vcpkg integrate install" to use with VS Code in MAC OS Monterey

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, vcpkg

I am trying to use vcpkg to manage packages for my cpp projects.

I have installed from git as instructed, and having error when it comes to "vcpkg integrate install".

The error message says that

"write_contents(.../.vcpkg/vcpkg.path.txt): No such file or directory"

I am using MAC Monterey and VScode.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

After trying

```
./vcpkg/vcpkg integrate install --debug
```

It told me that it was not able to find the file "vcpkg/vcpkg.path.txt"

I simply created a file in my home directory

```
mkdir ~/.vcpkg
touch ~/.vcpkg/vcpkg.path.txt
```

This resolved the issue